# Hash em url com plugin JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber se alguem conhece algum plug-in ou script, que pegue a hash da url. Mas que seja usual em todos os navegadores. Que pegue mais de uma hash por url. 
Eu sei que existem diversos exemplos na internet, mas fico com receio de não funcionar em todos os navegadores. Por isso gostaria de uma indicação de um script 100% usual com os detalhes dados acima..

Comment: Seria interessante descreveres melhor o que queres fazer para percebermos o que precisas.

Comment: Então Sergio, eu gostaria de pegar a URL: ex: tag?#1354#maria. Pegar essas Hashs, mas algo que seja compatível com navegadores tanto antigos quanto atuais. Existe algum plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Caso esse parâmetro esteja em query string eu utilizo essa função e funciona no IE, Chrome e Mozilla.

```
 function getQueryString(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? null : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
};
```

Para utilizar basta chamar a query string que o método retornará o valor.

Exemplo

URL: http://localhost/?hash=asdf01215df

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
           var queryString = getQueryString("hash");
           alert(queryString); // irá imprimir asdf01215df
      </script>
```